# How to get values from a dropDownList and pass to another one using onChange in yii

Tags: ajax, yii

How do I get `values(id)` from a `dropDownList` and pass them to another one using `onChange` in yii?

```
<?php 
  echo $form->dropDownList($model,'sub_cat_id', array('promot'=>'-- Select --')+CHtml::listData(Catagories::model()->findAll(), 'id_cat', 'cat_name','cat_name'));                                              
?>
```

This is the first box, I want to get the id and pass to send one `where parent_id = 1` using `onChange`:

```
 <?php  
   echo $form->dropDownList($model,'sub_cat_id', array('empty'=>'-- Select --')+CHtml::listData(Catagories::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('parent_id'=>'1')),'id_cat','cat_name')); 
 ?>
```

Comment: I asked a similar question recently. Have a look.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937382/yii-populate-a-dropdown-on-select-of-another

Comment: Hi actually i didn't get your post,Let me know how to do....